# How to update state inside an addListener React Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Greetings to everyone,

I have really no experience in working with class components as I have been using the normal functional easy ones but recently started a project that requires the class component,

I have the following state variable -

```
  this.state = {
      current: "City X"
    };
```

Now in the methods for this class, I have a function -

```
 codeAddress(geocoder) {
        var marker;
        var data = this.state.data;
    
     marker.addListener("click", () => {
    
             
              // On click - The state value of 'current' should update to another value.

this.setState({current: 'City Y'});

                
    
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(54.976713, -1.60728);
    
                    
    
                    var request = {
                      origin: pointA,
                      destination: location,
                      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
                    };
                    directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
                      if (status == 'OK') {
                        directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
                      }
                    });
    
    
                  }, 2000)
                });
    }
```

However this code gives an error that `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')`

I have binded all the functions in the constructor and tried a bunch of different techniques of updating the state value but haven't been able to figure it out exactly just yet.

Comment: And what is a marker?

Comment: Oh its just a marker, Google Maps API, I'm basically trying to set the state to something when the marker is clicked,

Comment: The problems is in the scope of `this` check the example [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 0):

For what it looks like it seems like you have a problem with the scope of `this`,
Did you bind the `codeAddress` Function inside the constructor?

```js
constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    this.codeAddress = this.codeAddress.bind(this);
  }
```

So what is happening is that JavaScript is trying to access the this but inside a normal
Function (not an arrow function) and the this is just an object with no properties in your case.
With the `bind` Function we are binding the `this` we have in our class to that function so when you call `this` It will get you the `this` Of the class itself and will let you access all of it’s properties

Comment: Hey there, Thank you for the detailed response, However I did bind the `codeAddress` in my constructor and I'm still getting the same error so far.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up on my previous answer
One solution you can do is to add a binding function and call it inside the callback

```
const setCurrentOnMarkerClick = (function() { 
        this.setState({current: 'City Y'});

            

              setTimeout(() => {
                var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(54.976713, -1.60728);

                

                var request = {
                  origin: pointA,
                  destination: location,
                  travelMode: 'DRIVING'
                };
                directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
                  if (status == 'OK') {
                    directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
                  }
                });


              }, 2000)
            });          
    }).bind(this);

 marker.addListener("click", setCurrentOnMarkerClick)
```

Comment: Hey, I just tried this and the same error still remains unfortunately